# Enumerating sets of Dominoes of cardinality $n$ with each number occuring an even number of times

Tags: combinatorics

There are $100$ domino tiles [$\{i,j\}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlRis.png) with $i,j \in \{1, 2,\dots, 25\}$ and $i\neq j$ in a sack, with no domino tile occurring twice. Each number $1, 2,\dots, 25$ is on exactly $8$ dominoes.

How may ways to pick $n \leq 100$ dominoes, such that each number $1, 2,\dots, 25$ is an even number of times in the selection?

So for example for $n = 3$, a valid selection would be $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\}$ if these dominoes were in the sack.

Or is there an efficient algorithm to answer the above question, in the case that the contents of the sack are known?